# Countif() if any of the comma-separated values in Sheet1(A1) appears in Sheet2(A:A)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a formula to count the occurrences of Barcodes in `Sheet2` which is comma-separated in `Sheet1`, where I'd like to summarize the occurrences.

- `Sheet1` is a product-list. A product can have multiple Barcodes (`Column B`).
- `Sheet2` is a input of Barcodes which occurrences I'd like to count in `Sheet1`.
- `Column C` in `Sheet1` is the Count-formula. For the example I've added a `Countif()` that I used until recently where a product now can have more then one Barcode.

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jYMc1Z_x7ZX4jUSo49Hto4rxV1MyPqfUsr9F8VvaKZ0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,SPLIT(B2,","))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,MMULT(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A, SPLIT(B2:B10, ",")), 
 SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(B2:B10, ",")), 1, 1, 0))))
```

[image]